# Mono.Math.BigInteger is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, mono, biginteger

So I'm working on a program in C# using ideone and I'm working with Mono for the first time. I'm trying to use the BigInteger class (Mono.Math.BigInteger) but I keep getting errors. Here's me code below. What is going on and how do I fix it? Thanks.

```
using System;
using Mono.Math;

public class TFIB
{       
    public static int Main()
    {       
        const int FIB_SEQUENCE_SIZE = 300;
        BigInteger[] FibonacciSequence = new BigInteger[FIB_SEQUENCE_SIZE];

        // Calculate Fibonacci Sequence
        FibonacciSequence[0] = 0;
        FibonacciSequence[1] = 1;

        for (int i = 2; i < FIB_SEQUENCE_SIZE; i++)
        {
            FibonacciSequence[i] = FibonacciSequence[i - 1] + FibonacciSequence[i - 2];
        }

        while (true)
        {
            string[] tokenInput = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            Mono.Math.BigInteger lowerBound = Mono.Math.BigInteger.Parse(tokenInput[0]);
            BigInteger upperBound = BigInteger.Parse(tokenInput[1]);
            if (lowerBound == 0 && upperBound == 0)
            {
                break;  // ending sequence found
            }
            else
            {
                // find the number of fibonacci sequences
                int numbersInRange = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < FIB_SEQUENCE_SIZE; i++)
                {
                    if (FibonacciSequence[i] >= lowerBound)
                    {
                        if (FibonacciSequence[i] <= upperBound)
                        {
                            numbersInRange++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;   // there is nothing more to find
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(numbersInRange);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

prog.cs(9,13): error CS0122: `Mono.Math.BigInteger' is inaccessible due to its protection level
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
prog.cs(9,23): error CS0122:`Mono.Math.BigInteger[]' is inaccessible due to its protection level
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
prog.cs(23,27): error CS0122: `Mono.Math.BigInteger' is inaccessible due to its protection level
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
prog.cs(24,17): error CS0122:`Mono.Math.BigInteger' is inaccessible due to its protection level
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 0 warnings

Answer (score 4):

`Mono.Math.BigInteger` is in the `Mono.Security.dll`, are you sure you are referencing the right assembly? The compilation errors you are getting suggest you aren't.

While `BigInteger` is used (internally) inside `mscorlib.dll`, you can't reference it from there.

Alternatively, there's the 4.0 [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) implementation that you can use by changing your `using` to `System.Numerics` and referencing `System.Numerics.dll`, but it doesn't look as optimized as the `Mono.Math` one, at least for now.

Unfortunately, Ideone does not seem to allow customizing assembly references, which means that you won't be able to compile either solution at all. You can only file a bug with [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: So then what do I do here? Once again I'm using ideone (and I have no other options) so I don't believe I have control over anything other than what code I type. I reference Mono.Math but when I change it to Mono.Security, it says it can't find type or namespace BigInteger. So what is the solution?

Comment: @BenjaminGiles sorry, but this is a missing feature in Ideone.com , you can't add assembly references at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the .NET 4.0 framework (using dmcs)

Also, from t[his page](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/NET-Framework/30412472/orcas--systemnumericbiginteger--unable-to-compile.aspx):

> Yes, but then see this:
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/04/20/visual-studio-code-
>   name-orcas-beta-1-has-been-released-inbar-gazit.aspx
>
> In particular:
>
> some good and constructive feedback from customers and partners that
>   are interested in extended numerical types. We have learned that there
>   are some potential improvements that we can make to this type to better
>   serve their needs. As such, we **decided to remove BigInteger** from the
>   Beta 1 release of Orcas so that we can address these issues and
>   concerns. -- Jon Skeet"

Comment: I'm using ideone and this needs to be submitted to an online judge. I don't think I can target the .NET 4.0 framework.

Comment: @BenjaminGiles: never mind, I think IdeOne uses dmcs (but doesn't configure the bits for example `dynamic`...?) - regardless, BigInteger seems out for now (see updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can't reference the assembly, just add BigInteger.cs to your project directly.  Source can be found here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Math/BigInteger.cs