# How to convert an Int64 to BigInteger in Mono C#?

Tags: c#, mono, biginteger

In MS C#, the following constructor works:

```
Int64 a = 123;
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(a);
```

This does not work in Mono.  The compile complains that it can't convert from long to BigInteger (CS1502, CS1503).

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Anything here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632692/mono-math-biginteger-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the BigInteger constructors on Mono, http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aMono.Math.BigInteger%2fC

```
BigInteger()    
BigInteger(BigInteger)  
BigInteger(byte[])  
BigInteger(uint)    
BigInteger(uint[])  
BigInteger(ulong)   
BigInteger(BigInteger, uint)    
BigInteger(BigInteger.Sign, uint)
```

There is no constructor accepting `long (which is the same as Int64)`

Try `BigInteger bi = new BigInteger((ulong)a);`

or 
`BigInteger bi = new BigInteger((uint)a);`

Comment: Yes, it looks like `Mono.Math.BigInteger` is an unsigned (that is, always non-negative) integer, a "natural" number. When `a` is of a signed type, and is not `const`, it can't be guaranteed compile-time that `a` is non-negative. So make `a` constant, or check for its sign and cast to `UInt64`.

Answer (score 1):

Mono.Math.BigInteger has only constructor accepting ulong. Isn't it System.Numerics.BigInteger You want to use?

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Numerics/System.Numerics/BigInteger.cs